# There exist arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive integers that are not square-free

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $a$ and $n$ be positive integers. A sequence of $n$ consecutive integers $(a, a+1, a+2,...,a+(n-1))$ is called a *Wolczuk* of length $n$ if every integer in the sequence is divisible by some perfect square greater than $1$. 
Example: $(48, 49, 50)$ is Wolczuk of length $3$ since $2^2\mid48$, $7^2\mid49$, $5^2\mid50$.
Prove that for any positive integer $n$, there exist infinitely many Wolczuks of length $n$.

I would really appreciate any help, it would be great if you prove this by Modular Arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, there exists $a\in\mathbb Z$ with
$$\left\{\begin{align*}
a&\equiv0\pmod{2^2}\\
a&\equiv-1\pmod{3^2}\\
a&\equiv-2\pmod{5^2}\\
a&\equiv-3\pmod{7^2}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
a&\equiv-(n-1)\pmod{p_n^2}
\end{align*}\right.$$